# deleting a directory in solaris,Ksh

Tags: unix, shell

```
rm -r /cbbconfg/BRCH/tmp
rm: cannot determine if this is an ancestor of the current working directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm` is confused as to whether you are removing a directory that is part of the present working directory. check to see if there is a link or something that is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember this is an old bug in Solaris 10.

Ah-ha.

Have a look at this [OpenSolaris bug report](http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6389212).

What about trying to do the delete recursively using find? Maybe something like:

```
find /cbbconfg -depth -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in the following way!! I have moved to that directory and ran the command :D